# Is there any JavaScript function in some library for turning simple wiki mark up (given as multi line string) into html?

Tags: javascript, html, string, parsing, wiki

What I generally need is simple - opensource library with function that will turn given wiki mark up string into html. If you can write such function - please post it here.

It shall be tolerant to html objects inserts like YouTube videos, mathml and TeX inside that string (much alike math.stackexchange)

So is there any such function in some JavaScript library?

Here is a little sample example to try on.

```
Header 1
========

Header 2
--------

# Header 1 #

## Header 2 ##

###### Header 6

=Header1?=

 = Header1? =

<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/20344220" width="400" height="225" frameborder="0"></iframe><p><a href="http://vimeo.com/20344220">Drawing Inspiration</a> from <a href="http://vimeo.com/user153493">Wesley Louis</a> on <a href="http://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.</p>

<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/wV1FrqwZyKw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

*   Abacus
    * answer
*   Bubbles
    1.  bunk
    2.  bupkis
        * BELITTLER
    3. burper
*   Cunning
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Would [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) be OK?

See the [Markdown dingus](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/dingus).

Comment: But "Markdown requires Perl 5.6.0 or later. Welcome to the 21st Century. Markdown also requires the standard Perl library module Digest::MD5, which is probably already installed on your server." so it seems like its not so pure JS one...

Comment: Markdown was originally implemented in Perl but since then it has been implemented in many programming languages, including JavaScript in the browser, with no need for any scripting on the server. It was even implemented as [a jQuery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/markdown). Also google for markdown-js, or markdown javascript, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, http://goessner.net/articles/wiky/ it can also do the reverse operation.

Comment: So I Tested it. Firest of all it is more or less good for Iframes - it keeps tham. But for other html it is quite a hell... They have http://goessner.net/articles/wiky/WikyBox.html where you can try stuff... I need something with better raw html eating capabileties, althow math is grate in that lib I plan on using http://www.mathjax.org/ for math.